# remembering the value of a counter

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

int input, counter,value;
int ABC[3];

counter = 0;

scanf("%d", &input);

switch (input)
{
case 1:
    if (counter >=4)
    {
        printf("Error\n"); 
    }
    scanf("%d", &value);
    ABC[counter]= value;
    printf("ABC[%d] is %d \n", counter, ABC[counter]);
    counter++;
    main();
    break;

case 2: //do anything
    main();
    break;
default: 
    printf("a is anything\n"); 
    break;
}

return 0;
}
```

I want to put in array ABC every time i choose case 1 a value, until array ABC is full. My problem is, that i can only enter in this programm values into ABC[0] . Is there any way, to remember the value of counter, so it's not always 0? Maybe using if-statement? But how to formulate an if-statement in this programm, which is only once in the beginning true?

But ABC should also be allowed to have empty space

Comment: Calling `main` is illegal. If you want to have recursive code, you need to extract it to a new function. Although, you probably could achieve the desired behavior with a loop instead of recursion (which would help with the fact that you have a new set of local variables for every call).

Comment: you need to put a loop around all the code that is now between main and return.

Comment: @AndrewMedico `main` can recursive call in C(C++ cannot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After "counter++" you are re-calling your "main" function, that reinitializes your counter to 0. You should use a loop:

```
int counter = 0;
do
{
    // Your scanf goes here
    switch(scanf_result)
    {
    // Add your case labels here
    default: // Incorrect input? Let's start again!
        continue;
    };
    counter++;
}
while(counter < 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that declaring counter outside the main function, would make it global scope.

in this way everytime you call main(); you reset the value to 0.

so write int counter = 0 before the main declaration, at row number 2.